# Select First Item in Dropdown List

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I just want to select the first item by default but the drop down list has a blank item selected.

How I can resolve it? Thank you!

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Add()
{
   var sportList = new SelectList(db.Sports.OrderBy(s => s.Name).ToList(), "ID", "Name");

   UserTournamentModel m = new UserTournamentModel();
   m.SportList = sportList;
   m.SportID = Guid.Parse(sportList.FirstOrDefault().Value);

   return View(m);
}
```

and here

```
<div class="editor-label" style="width: 70px;">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SportID, Model.SportList)
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`SelectList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492553.aspx) constructor overload that accepts the selected item:

```
var orderedSportList = db.Sports.OrderBy(s => s.Name);
var sportList = new SelectList(orderedSportList.ToList(), "ID", "Name",
     orderedSportList.FirstOrDefault());
```

Comment: Hmmm... Somehow it doesn't work... But it should.  I've debugged the SelectedValue Property has correct value.

Comment: Do you have any javascript that would affect it?

Comment: May be because of the event? It is not   [HttpPost] ... It is a form to create the Tournament.

Comment: It's possible, but without being able to debug it on my own I can't say for sure. I do know that the `SelectList` constructor I suggested has worked in the limited circumstances I've had to use it in though, so it's probably related to something project specific.